# Need help solving this minimization function of jerk by use of Euler-Poisson equation

Tags: proof-writing, minimal-polynomials

I need help solving this. In the picture below a paper explains why that the jerk (third derivative of position) is already cost optimal. So this means that a sixth order polynomial is already jerk cost optimal.

In measurements of my minimization algorithm I want to obtain a minimal jerk root mean square (rms) value. But the optimized function I get is the same as a sixth order polynomial. So my hypothesis is that jerk also is rms minimal. I want to proof this mathematically.

In the picture below is the proof of cost, the proof uses $x(t)$ and $y(t)$:

[First part of cost jerk proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkLeC.png)

[Second part of cost jerk proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlDqJ.png)

Now I want to proof the same for rms but only for a single variable $\theta(t)$.
This is what I already have but I can't proof it further.

$jerk: \dddot{\theta}(t)=\frac{d^3\theta(t)}{dt^3}$

H-function represents the rms of the function:

$H(\dddot{\theta}(t))=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T_2-T_1}\int_{T_1}^{T_2} [\dddot{\theta}(t)]^2 \,dx}$

I'm a engineering major and not math. So if possible please explain a bit.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.